# Single instance windows on visionOS

Tags: visionos

It appears that `Window` is not available on visionOS, only `WindowGroup`. If I want to have a window with only one instance (say, a Menu or similar), how can I ensure that each time I call `openWindow`, the same window appears, and a new one is not created?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this may be intentional to allow users to 'find' windows they've misplaced. It looks like it will be easy to lose things in the environment and *perhaps* it will make sense from a UX perspective to allow the user to have multiple sets of controls around their environment.

If you want to control only opening one instance of a WindowGroup, then dismissing it first, before opening is a reasonable way, as that will bring it back to where the user is looking.

```
@Environment(\.openWindow) private var openWindow
@Environment(\.dismissWindow) private var dismissWindow

Button("open") {
  dismissWindow(id: "targetView")
  openWindow(id: "targetView")
}
```

Otherwise keeping track of the window lifecycle using the [scene phase](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scenephase), combined with `.onDisappear` to track when a view is dismissed is more involved but also works. `controlActiveState` would be the preferred method, but that seems unavailable on visionOS (for now).

Answer (score 1):

I have a rather quick and dirty solution that did the job for me. I had no other idea than just caching the windows ID's in some global `Set` and check against that whenever opening a new window.

E.g. inside of your `App` conforming struct:

```swift
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    static var openendWindowsIDs: Set<String> = []
    //...
}
```

Then wherever you open that new window you can check against that `Set` (The following is just an example resulting in some boilerplate so you would probably abstract it away somehow)

```swift
Button {
    let windowID = "myWindowsUniqueId"
    if !MyApp.openendWindowsIDs.contains(windowID) {
        openWindow(id: windowID)
    }
    MyApp.openendWindows.insert(windowID)
}
```

*(Or even do not show this button or whatever triggers the window at all by checking before)*

Also do not forget to remove the window's id somewhere it makes sense, e.g. in the main view of that window you are closing:

```swift
.onDisappear(perform: {
    MyApp.openendWindows.remove("myWindowsUniqueId")
})
```

### What's mentioned in the docs but did *not* work for me:

The documentation for `WindowGroup` mentions:

> If a window with a binding to the same value that you pass to the openWindow action already appears in the user interface, the system brings the existing window to the front rather than opening a new window. I still always got new instances. That is why I use the example above now.

Together with this code example:

```swift
WindowGroup(for: Message.ID.self) { $messageID in
    MessageDetail(messageID: messageID)
}
```

How I understood this: If you call `openWindow` with the same (here) `messageID` passed, there should not be opened a new window. However, I did not get this to work.